# Prolog unweighted graph distances off by 1

Tags: path, prolog, graph-theory, weighted

So I am trying to find paths and their lengths for unweighted graphs. Here is my code; you give it a relation, a start, and end, as well as the length. The code works however it returns a length that is 1 less than needed.

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

edge(1,2).    
edge(1,4).    
edge(1,3).    
edge(2,3).    
edge(2,5).    
edge(3,4).    
edge(3,5).    
edge(4,5).

connected(X,Y) :- 
    edge(X,Y) 
    ; 
    edge(Y,X).

path(Rel,A,B,Path,Len) :-    
       travel(Rel,A,B,[A],Q,Len),
       reverse(Q,Path).

travel(Rel,A,B,P,[B|P],L) :-    
       call(Rel, A, B), L is 1 .

travel(Rel,A,B,Visited,Path,L) :-    
       call(Rel,A,C),
       C \== B,
       \+member(C,Visited),
       travel(Rel,C,B,[C|Visited],Path,L1),
       L is L1 + 1.
```

All these edges have weight/distance of 1 however given a query such as

```
?- path(connected, 1, 5, Path, Length).
```

every length returned is 1 less then it should be.

Any suggestions helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of trying to fix the way you compute the length of the path in your predicate `travel` from experience I know that refactoring Prolog code when processing list to calculate another property is not hard and commonly done.

So instead this refactors the predicate `reverse/2`. To refactor `reverse/2` we will first need working code for `reverse/2`:

```
% Reverse using accumulator
rev(List,Rev) :-
  rev(List,[],Rev) .

rev([],A,A).
rev([H|T],A,R) :-
  rev(T,[H|A],R).
```

Examples of `rev/2`

```
?- rev([],L).
L = [].

?- rev([a],L).
L = [a].

?- rev([a,b],L).
L = [b, a].

?- rev([a,b,c],L).
L = [c, b, a].
```

Now to refactor `rev/2` to calculate the length.

```
rev_n(List,Rev,N) :-
  rev_n(List,[],Rev,N) .

rev_n([],A,A,0).
rev_n([H|T],A,R,N) :-
  rev_n(T,[H|A],R,N0),
  N is N0 + 1.
```

Examples of `rev_n/2`

```
?- rev_n([],L,N).
L = [],
N = 0.

?- rev_n([a],L,N).
L = [a],
N = 1.

?- rev_n([a,b],L,N).
L = [b, a],
N = 2.

?- rev_n([a,b,c],L,N).
L = [c, b, a],
N = 3.
```

Lastly just modify your code to use `rev_n/2` and remove the no longer needed portions of your code that calculated N.

```
path_2(Rel,A,B,Path,Len) :-
    travel_2(Rel,A,B,[A],Q),
    rev_n(Q,Path,Len).

travel_2(Rel,A,B,P,[B|P]) :-
    call(Rel, A, B).

travel_2(Rel,A,B,Visited,Path) :-
    call(Rel,A,C),
    C \== B,
    \+member(C,Visited),
    travel_2(Rel,C,B,[C|Visited],Path).
```

Example:

```
?- path_2(connected, 1, 5, Path, Length).
Path = [1, 2, 5],
Length = 3 ;
Path = [1, 2, 3, 5],
Length = 4 ;
Path = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
Length = 5 ;
Path = [1, 4, 5],
Length = 3 ;
Path = [1, 4, 3, 5],
Length = 4 ;
Path = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5],
Length = 5 ;
Path = [1, 3, 5],
Length = 3 ;
Path = [1, 3, 4, 5],
Length = 4 ;
Path = [1, 3, 2, 5],
Length = 4 ;
false.
```

---

A more practical way would also be to just use `length/2`

```
path_3(Rel,A,B,Path,Len) :-
    travel_2(Rel,A,B,[A],Q),
    reverse(Q,Path),
    length(Path,Len).

?- path_3(connected, 1, 5, Path, Length).
Path = [1, 2, 5],
Length = 3 ;
Path = [1, 2, 3, 5],
Length = 4 ;
Path = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
Length = 5 ;
Path = [1, 4, 5],
Length = 3 ;
Path = [1, 4, 3, 5],
Length = 4 ;
Path = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5],
Length = 5 ;
Path = [1, 3, 5],
Length = 3 ;
Path = [1, 3, 4, 5],
Length = 4 ;
Path = [1, 3, 2, 5],
Length = 4 ;
false.
```