# Prolog - Path finding and length given Relation

Tags: prolog, path-finding

I just began learning Prolog and I wanted to understand Pathfinding better. I have a few examples of relationships, however, I don't know how to find the path and length of a relationships when the relationships are cyclical. I've been trying to create a list that documents visited nodes, but I keep receiving errors.

Below are a few examples as well as my attempt to find path given the relationship, source, target, pathlist, and length):

```
is_a(parallelogram, quadrilateral).
is_a(trapezoid, quadrilateral).
is_a(rhombus, parallelogram).
is_a(rectangle, parallelogram).
is_a(square, rhombus).
is_a(square, rectangle).

edge(a, b).
edge(b, c).
edge(c, d).
edge(d, a).

friend(alice, bob).
friend(bob, carol).
friend(carol, daniel).
friend(carol, eve).

friends(A,B) :- 
    friend(A,B); 
    friend(B,A).

transit(Rel, S, T) :- 
    call(Rel, S, X), 
    (X = T; transit(Rel, X, T)).

path_(Rel,Source,Target,Path,Len) :-
    path_(Rel,Source,Target,Path,Len,[]).

path_(Rel,Source,Target,Path,Len,Visited) :-
    transit(Rel,Source,Target),
    transit(Rel,Source,Mid),
    Mid == Target, !,
    append(Visited,[Source,Target],Path),
    length(Path,L),
    Len is L+1.

path_(Rel,Source,Target,Path,Len,Visited) :-
    transit(Rel,Source,Target),
    transit(Rel,Source,Mid),
    not(member(Mid,Visited)),
    path_(Rel,Mid,Target,Path,Len,[Source|Visited]).
```

The above is my second attempt, but I receive errors on everything. My first attempt only worked with non-cyclical paths, such as for the is_a relationships, which is noted below:

```
path0(Rel,From,To,[From,To],2) :-
    transit(Rel,From,To),
    call(Rel, From, To).

path0(Rel,From,To,[From|Xs],Len) :-
    transit(Rel,From,X),
    call(Rel,From,X),
    path0(Rel,X,To,Xs,_),
    length(Xs, L),
    Len is L+1.
```

Comment: Is this homework? In the last few days I have seen several questions like this.

Comment: Have you looked at other answers for the Prolog tag here. The question has been answered in many different ways.

Comment: I've seen one that is more specific to this assignment, but the approach was very different. I wanted to look for guidance in regards to the way I wanted to follow nodes in the graph, but maybe I didn't approach the problem the way I should have

Comment: `maybe I didn't approach the problem the way I should have` I wold agree with that.

Comment: Would you be able to link other answers?

Comment: See: [Prolog unweighted graph distances off by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53691761/1243762)